# Angular universal - get current url in server side

Tags: angular, angular-universal

The question may simple but I couldn't find working solution anywhere. I have a website where I have Angular SSR setup and want to get the current url in one of my Angular components. I have gone thru multiple sites and understood that I had to pass host information from universal server and get the same in Angular component.

My code snipet from server.ts file where I am passing the host information

```
  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, {
      req,
      providers: [
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl },
        { provide: 'host', useValue: req.get('host') }, // sending host name in provider
      ],
    });
  });
```

my host.ts file is as below,

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
export const HOST_ID = new InjectionToken<string>('host');
```

And this is how, I tried to get the host name in app component.ts which always gives me null value.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoading: boolean = false;
  constructor(
    @Optional() @Inject(HOST_ID) private host: InjectionToken<string>
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (platformServer) console.log(this.host);
  }
```

Angular version used is 9. Please someone shed some light on this issue. Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried https://angular.io/api/common/PlatformLocation service ?

Comment: yes tried now and I able to get the host name now. Thanks much @Chellappanவ

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you got this figured out already looking at the comments, but I'm wondering if the original issue in your code is that you are not actually using the `HOST_ID` injection token in your server's listener.

If you change your listener to something like this:

```js
// All regular routes use the Universal engine
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(indexHtml, {
    req,
    providers: [
      { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl },
      { provide: HOST_ID, useValue: req.get('host') }, // sending host name in provider
    ],
  });
});
```

I think your problem will be fixed.